# 'CoreMinimal.h' file not found when building on Unreal Engine on Mac

Tags: c++, unreal-4, macos

I'm trying out C++ on Unreal Engine 4.25 on Mac. If relevant, my Xcode version is 12. When I try to compile, there's an error: `'CoreMinimal.h' file not found`.

I've looked around and some solutions mention a workaround, which is to add the path to CoreMinimal.h into the .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json file. I did that:

```
...
    "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.25/Engine/**" // This is the filepath to CoreMinimal.h
    ],
...
```

I still get the same error. I couldn't find any other solution. Has someone found a solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem? I found the closest solution on YT: "Unreal Engine 4.25 & VS Code | Intellisense Bug & Include Errors Fix" https://youtu.be/yAUgFZh28aA  but it's still not working for me

Comment: @Sparky nope. i moved on to other things. maybe i should delete this question. anyway hope you have better luck with this

Comment: I have finally resolved all of the issues related to Intellisense and UE4 thanks to this VSCode extension: "VSCode/UE Intellisense Fixes Extension" https://gist.github.com/boocs/f63a4878156295b6e854cac68672f305#Extension-Settings

Comment: Also, please don't delete this post because this can help other people